# MapView not loading when running on CI

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, xctest, xcuitest

I have some XCUITests that need to tap annotations on a map, when I run the tests in my mac everything works fine, but when they run on CI the map doesn't load.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/B6YEG.jpg

Answer (score 0):

Ensure your CI device/simulator is connected to the internet. Your map load in CI may be slower than on a real device, so you may need to increase wait times.